# Jenkins Gradle test fails on Commons Configuration

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, apache-commons-config

I have a project that uses Apache Commons Configuration. The project is built using gradle. I have some unit test cases written on this project and gradle test works fine when run locally.

However when the unit tests are run in Jenkins it fails.
[Please see the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8AYa.png). The error seems to be to do  something with Commons Configuration that I am using. Please help.

```
org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationRuntimeException: No ConfigurationProvider registered for tag disabledAdministrativeMonitors
org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationRuntimeException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationRuntimeException: No ConfigurationProvider registered for tag disabledAdministrativeMonitors
at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.createConfigurationAt(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:752) ~[commons-configuration-1.6.jar:1.6]
at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.initCombinedConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:628) ~[commons-configuration-1.6.jar:1.6]
at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.getConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:560) ~[commons-configuration-1.6.jar:1.6]
```

Comment: Please add the error *as text* to your question.

Comment: I added the error as text.

Answer (score 1):

The ConfigurationProvider try to load a configuration xml file which is default the *config.xml*. 
In my case the project is build using Jenkins. Jenkins provides a *config.xml* in Jenkins home dir. This is loaded first instead of my desired one. Maybe that applies for you too?

Example Jenkins *config.xml*

```
<?xml version=’1.1' encoding=’UTF-8'?>
<hudson>
<disabledAdministrativeMonitors>
...
</disabledAdministrativeMonitors>
...
```